# Microsoft.DesktopBridge.props in a C project

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, nethack

I'm trying to build Nethack on Windows, and I get this error message:

```
"C:\NetHack-NetHack-3.6.6_Released\win\win32\vs2017\NetHack.sln" (Clean;Build target) (1) ->
"C:\NetHack-NetHack-3.6.6_Released\win\win32\vs2017\NetHackPackage.wapproj" (Clean target) (33) ->
  C:\NetHack-NetHack-3.6.6_Released\win\win32\vs2017\NetHackPackage.wapproj(27,3): error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\DesktopBridge\Microsoft.DesktopBridge.props" was not found. Confirm that the expression in the Import declaration "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\DesktopBridge\\Microsoft.DesktopBridge.props" is correct, and that the file
 exists on disk.
```

I get a similar error message when trying to build with VS 2017 instead of 2022, and when trying to build the latest 3.7 sources instead of 3.6.6.

I've never heard of Microsoft.DesktopBridge.props and there is no file by that name anywhere on my machine. Google throws up some results for that name (both here and on other sites), but all of them seem to be discussing .Net projects, and Nethack, in a counterexample to nominative determinism, has nothing whatsoever to do with .Net; it's a pure C program.

What's going on with this?

Comment: Do you have support for UWP apps installed? In the Visual Studio installer did you include the "Universal Windows Platform development' workload? The Desktop Bridge supports Windows desktop applications as Universal Windows Platform (UWP) apps.

Comment: This link(https://github.com/microsoft/Terminal/issues/482) give a suggestion to install UWP development tools. Does this can help you?